# Why does my overlay not transition while rerendering?

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions

I'm trying to transition a simple overlay if one of four thumbnails is clicked. My idea was to toggle the overlays opacity within the inline style of the element like this..

```
<div className='product-thumbnail-overlay' style={selectedThumbnail === id ? { opacity: 1 } : { opacity: 0 }}></div>
```

This is working until I wrap this code in a react function component to avoid repetitions of my code.

HTML

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Product.scss';
import ProductImage1 from '../assets/images/image-product-1.jpg';
import ProductImage2 from '../assets/images/image-product-2.jpg';
import ProductImage3 from '../assets/images/image-product-3.jpg';
import ProductImage4 from '../assets/images/image-product-4.jpg';
import ProductThumbnail1 from '../assets/images/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg';
import ProductThumbnail2 from '../assets/images/image-product-2-thumbnail.jpg';
import ProductThumbnail3 from '../assets/images/image-product-3-thumbnail.jpg';
import ProductThumbnail4 from '../assets/images/image-product-4-thumbnail.jpg';

const Product = () => {
    const [selectedThumbnail, setSelectedThumbnail] = useState(1);

    const getProductThumbnailById = (id) => {
        // get the imported product thumbnail
    };

    const ProductThumbnail = ({ id }) => {
        return (
            <div className='product-thumbnail-container' onClick={() => setSelectedThumbnail(id)}>
                <img src={getProductThumbnailById(id)} alt='thumbnail of product' className='product-thumbnail' />
                <div
                    className='product-thumbnail-overlay'
                    style={selectedThumbnail === id ? { opacity: 1 } : { opacity: 0 }}
                ></div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    return (
        <main>
            <div className='product-images'>
                <img src={ProductImage1} alt='product' className='product-image' />
                <div className='product-thumbnails'>
                    <ProductThumbnail id={1} />
                    <ProductThumbnail id={2} />
                    <ProductThumbnail id={3} />
                    <ProductThumbnail id={4} />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='product-details'></div>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Product;
```

important SCSS

```
.product-thumbnail-container {
    position: relative;
    flex: 20.5%;
    cursor: pointer;

    .product-thumbnail {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        border-radius: variables.$br;
    }

    .product-thumbnail-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        border: 2px solid variables.$clr_prim_orange;
        border-radius: variables.$br;
        transition: all 2000ms ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

Codepen with what im trying to accomplish (but with repetitions of code): https://codepen.io/Sandhexer/pen/JjLrZOQ?editors=0110

Codepen with current code: https://codepen.io/Sandhexer/pen/gOeGKpP?editors=0110

I think that the rerendering causes the element not to transition because the opacity doesnt really change. Is this right and does anyone know a solution or good workaround for this problem?

Comment: Could you provide your css? And preferably a Codepen or something, that helps us visualize what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Added the important css, one codepen with the working version and one codepen with my actual code.

Comment: Thanks. Both seem to work for me, in Chrome as well as Firefox. What browser are you using? Perhaps it just doesn't work in your local app due to css scoping, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I am using chrome too. The problem is that the transition does not work when clicking on a thumbnail.

Comment: Strange. Maybe it's a browser plugin that's blocking something. I'm using Chrome 103.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Hm. I am using Chrome 103.0.5060.134 (64-bit) on Windows 11. Are you sure you opened the correct codepen: https://codepen.io/Sandhexer/pen/gOeGKpP?editors=0110 ? To clarify it a little more: My point is the little fade in transition of the thumbnail overlay directly after clicking on it.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the clarification. It's so subtle that I didn't notice the difference. What I think the issue is, is that the component ProductThumbnail renders completely anew, which causes the transition not to take place probably. To be honest I don't know what the solution to this could be, other than a fade effect with a delay upon render maybe.

Comment: maybe use a hook that checks for changes of that property, then applying a classname that holds a classname which the higher opacity is applied to, in a setTimeout.